# What type of 3-pin connector is this?

Tags: power-supply, identification, connector, power-connector

Attached is an image of the connector to my desk lamp. I can't tell what type of connector it is. It's 3-pin but the far left hole doesn't appear to be used. The connector is attached to my desk lamp.

[image]

Comment: What is on the other end of this cable? A mains plug, a power adapter, or something else?

Comment: Can you advise the voltage, and perhaps show the mating connector?

Comment: At the other end of the pictured connector is a halogen desk lamp. The connector plugs into a 3 pin 120V AC to 12V AC 35VA power supply, which has since disintegrated.